# Jenkins server is not accessible by host name (ip address)

Tags: networking, jenkins

I setup jenkins on my Mac OS X with homebrew and it works just fine via `http://localhost:8080` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080`
I couldn't access jenkins instance via hostname/ipaddress:

```
 1. http://myjenkinshost.local:8080
 2. http://192.168.0.100:8080
```

Both links are  not accessible even from local computer (jenkins host itself).
Same time commands `ping 192.168.0.100` and `ping myjenkinshost.local` work just fine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It turned out that launch agent was configured to listen only 127.0.0.1 (or localhost).
To fixed that edit jenkins agent's plist:

```
nano /Users/admin/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist
```

and modify `httpListenAddress` to `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs$
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.jenkins</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
      <string>-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true</string>
      <string>-jar</string>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/jenkins/libexec/jenkins.war</string>
      <string>--httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0</string>
      <string>--httpPort=8080</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: hi. i installed the osx package version of jenkins from there website and could not locate the plist file anywhere. Do you have any ideas to where it could be for the installed package version?

Comment: The default is 0.0.0.0, so you can also just remove the line

Comment: "turns out that this file only exists at run time. The config file that is actually used is located at `/usr/local/opt/jenkins/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`"    -via: https://michaelheap.com/changing-the-httplistenaddress-for-jenkins-on-osx/

Comment: jonney the official jenkins wiki mentions how to do this. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Thanks+for+using+OSX+Installer. Look for "Starting/stopping the service"

Comment: See [@jinjorge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755250/2291928) if you're using Homebrew. When using `brew services`, don't edit `/Users/admin/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`. The LaunchAgent plist file will get copied to/overwritten by `brew services` with whatever is in the `/usr/local/Cellar/jenkins/2.xxx/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist` version of the file linked to by `/usr/local/opt/jenkins`.

Answer (score 14):

The correct location of the file to edit is `/usr/local/opt/jenkins/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

Found the answer [here](https://michaelheap.com/changing-the-httplistenaddress-for-jenkins-on-osx/)

Comment: This worked for me. The accepted answer above was overwritten every time I restarted Jenkins.

Answer (score 9):

At my macOS 11.4 Big Sur installation the plist file was found here:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.xxx.x/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist
```

Changing ip address to 0.0.0.0 worked as described.

Comment: This is the only answer working on Big Sur. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for adding Big Sur location!

Comment: Thanks it is worked for Big Sur Location, thanks a lot @cyx

Answer (score 3):

By starting jenkins using `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart` instead of `sudo service jenkins start` started the browser access. I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I came across something like this but, it was for windows,I'm sure the steps to resolve will be the same,Please give it a try:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/how-can-i-open-port-8080-of-mac-os-x-lion

Answer (score 1):

If your Jenkins running through Homebrew (macos), **don't touch** `/Users/admin/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

Use this one: `/usr/local/Cellar/jenkins/2.xxx/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

Change **httpListenAddress** to **0.0.0.0**

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have installed Jenkins LTS using Homebrew(macos)

   [macOS Installers for Jenkins LTS](https://www.jenkins.io/download/lts/macos/)

2. The path of the file homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist is:

   ```
    /opt/homebrew/opt/jenkins-lts/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist
   ```
3. Since the the folder opt is a hidden folder on macOS. You will need to do the following to see it in finder.

   Open Macintosh HD in finder -> and press cmd + shift + [.]

   This will reveal all hidden folders.
4. You now have everything you need to make the required changes. As stated in previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins running through Homebrew (macOS Big Sur),

First things first, you need to unhide the hidden folders.

Since the folder is a hidden folder on macOS. so you will need to do the following things to unhide the folder.

Open Macintosh HD in finder -> and **press cmd + shift + . (dot)**

This will reveal all hidden folders.

After you unhidden the folder, paste the below command in the terminal:

```
nano /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.xxx/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist
```

**Change httpListenAddress 127.0.0.1** to **0.0.0.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs$
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.jenkins</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
      <string>-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true</string>
      <string>-jar</string>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/jenkins/libexec/jenkins.war</string>
      <string>--httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0</string>
      <string>--httpPort=8080</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Once the above steps are done, you can access the Jenkins using hostname or public ip address.