# how to change jenkins local host to different ip in ubuntu for all linux based

Tags: jenkins

How to change `jenkins` `127.0.0.1:80` to different IP like `192.168.1.2:80`
so that I can access `jenkins` over LAN?

Comment: How did you deploy Jenkins? Standalone or in a container?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins server is not accessible by host name (ip address)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570128/jenkins-server-is-not-accessible-by-host-name-ip-address)

Comment: this is too long process.

Answer (score 1):

i have resolve this .
in /etc/hosts i have added ip address of `192.168.1.2` 
and stop firewall `sudo ufw disable`
now i was able to access jenkins from other machine in LAN.