# Accessing Jenkins on Mac OS X from another machine

Tags: macos, networking, jenkins, router, portforwarding

I want to reach Jenkins from both behind the router and the internet.

**Pretty straightforward setup:**

Internet > Router > Mac > Jenkins

**Known items:**

- From the router, I can see the machine's internal IP, which I'll call "X.X.X.X".
- Then there's the Jenkins URL location configuration in Jenkins:

[image]

**Goals**

1. I want to be able to access the Jenkins site from any machine
   already behind the router. I thought that I could use the X.X.X.X IP
   address as the above Jenkins URL but this didn't work.
2. Second, I want to be able to reach the Jenkins site from outside the
   router. Then I can configure Jenkins anywhere as well as use
   web-hooks when there are changes.

   I assume I then need to know the IP address of the router but that's about all I know.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I did find a solution to this. If someone is interested I will post my solution.

Comment: Hi, can you please share your solution ?

Comment: Done. This machine is no longer active so I had to write it up from memory. Good luck and let me know how it goes.

Comment: can you add the solution

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to connect to a Jenkins instance on Mac OS X from outside your router, although it's probably very similar on another OS like Windows or Linux.

1. Give your Jenkins machine a static IP address in Settings. We'll refer to it as `jenkins_machine_static_ip` for the purposes of these instructions:

   - Go to *Settings* > *Network* > *Advanced...* > *TCP/IP*
   - Copy the *IPv4 Address* (it'll be your `jenkins_machine_static_ip`), and also copy the *Subnet Mask*, & *Router*
   - Select *Configure IPv4* > *Manually*
   - Fill in copied info and select 'OK'
2. In your router's admin panel, assign the same `jenkins_machine_static_ip` to the *Mac Address* of your Jenkins machine.

   Access to the router admin panel depends on your router.

   You can find your *Mac Address* on your Jenkins machine as follows:

   - Go to *Settings* > *Network* > *Advanced...* > *Hardware*
3. Configure the *Jenkins URL* as `http://jenkins_machine_static_ip:pick_a_port`, where `jenkins_machine_static_ip` is the same one from steps 1&2 and `pick_a_port` is any unused port.

   - The *Jenkins URL* can be configured in your Jenkins web portal by following this path:
     *Jenkins* > *Manage Jenkins* > *Configure System* > *Jenkins Location*
   - See the image in the original question.
4. Set up port forwarding on your router by picking an arbitrary router port (we'll call it `router_forwarded_port`) and forwarding it to `http://machine_static_ip:pick_a_port`, which you set up in #3.

You can now access your Jenkins instance from outside the network by accessing your router's IP and the forwarding port. You can get your router's external IP address here: [Router_IP](https://www.whatismyip.com/)

The address you need to connect to is: `Router_IP:router_forwarded_port/`

Comment: Helpful, thanks! In my case, Configure IPv4 _Manually_ stopped my machine from connecting to the internet, I need to select _"Using DHCP with manual address"_ instead. Finally, I also needed this answer to get going: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26616131/1602875

Comment: @Mete nice! apparently I've visited that question/answer as well

Comment: @Mete, configure IPv4 with manually how do you do that? Can you add more information. how can you do two things

Comment: @kraftydevil what do you mean by step 2 are you talking about changing the actual MAC Address that comes with the hardware?

Comment: @keil - I don't think so, but it's hard to remember what I meant there precisely. My best guess is that you want to somehow associate the static ip with a particular mac address that you see from your router admin. The configuration is done in the router admin, but I don't have that same router or this instance of Jenkins anymore to check