# Not able to enter Jenkins (Mac) using network IP

Tags: macos, jenkins, connection, ip

I'm trying to setup Jenkins on my MacMini server. I've installed it using official docs and everything works, except accessing Jenkins using local network ip. I

'm able to enter using localhost:8080, but not able to reach it from 192.168.1.X:8080 from other network device or even from the same mac server.

I've already tried instructions from this question
[Accessing Jenkins on Mac OS X from another machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159576/accessing-jenkins-on-mac-os-x-from-another-machine)
but no effect.

It looks like Jenkins does not open to external connections or something. My browser finds Jenkins address, but it says "Not able to connect", just like if there is no such port (8080).

I've created a test http server, just to see if my Mac is reachable and ports are open, and everything works fine. Im able to enter an http, ssh, VNC using network address, but not able to enter Jenkins using it's port.

Does anybody knows why?

Comment: This is probably because you need to open port 8080 in the firewall on your server.

Comment: If I remember exactly, in Jenkins Admin configuration, there is a place to config the Jenkins server IP/hostname, change it to your Mac ip.