# Access Jenkins by IP address from "outside the network"

Tags: macos, jenkins

I am using Jenkins on MacOS (Monterey) and I want to be able to access my Jenkins from any (outside) network using my ip address.

- I have updated the `--httpListenAddress` to `0.0.0.0` and restarted Jenkins.
- I have checked for port 8080 to be open to inbound traffic.

I have been able to access this Jenkins from devices on the same network but not from an outside network.

I was able to achieve everything I wanted when using an AWS EC2 instance (by adding security group rules) but *not* able to do the same for a local Jenkins on my machine.
Any help/advice would be great! (Maybe without using a 3rd party service?)

Thank you.

Comment: are you forwarding port 8080 from your router to your machine?

Comment: @ivanvolkov Yes, this answer here helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159576/accessing-jenkins-on-mac-os-x-from-another-machine