# Install Jenkins on windows server and access it using VM's external ip [google-compute-engine]

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a VM instance with windows OS (windows-server-2019-dc-v20200211) in Google cloud.Established RDP connection and installed Jenkins on the VM, but how can I access it from other networks using the VM's external ip?

Could someone help me on this!!

Note: I want to install Jenkins in windows server and not on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you should check the following:

First, make sure your local firewall on windows server is enabled and allows connections on port 8080. Secondly, Network ACL for both incoming traffic on TCP 8080 and outcoming traffic on TCP port 8080 should be allowed.

Also check some of these stackoverflow use cases for more help: [1]https://superuser.com/questions/1212645/cannot-expose-jenkins-externally [2]https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/how-can-i-open-port-8080-of-mac-os-x-lion [3] [Jenkins server is not accessible by host name (ip address)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570128/jenkins-server-is-not-accessible-by-host-name-ip-address)